Jsonata Transformation to extract a value and make it a key
Jsonata newbie here. I need help with Jsonata Transformation to extract a value from json element and make it as key .
{

"key-1":[{

"id":"a",

"value":2.3

},{

"id":"b",

"value":2.3

}],

"key-2":[{
"id":"c",

"value":2.4

},{
"id":"d",

"value":2.5
}]

}


I want it to transform to "id" as key object as shown below
{
    "a": {
        "value": 2.3
    },
    "b": {
        "value": 2.3
    },
    "c": {
        "value": 2.4
    },
    "d": {
        "value": 2.5
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The following expression will do this:
*{id: {'value': value}}
See https://try.jsonata.org/BVQvBeMU9
